# gcc throwing error while compiling the code having GObject related libraraies in the C file on MAC

Tags: c, macos, gcc, compiler-errors, glib

Have a simple C program using glib library for referencing and dereferencing GObject. I wrote the code on ubuntu and have installed glib library on it.

Running the command

```sh
gcc *.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0` -o test
```

works fine.

Now I tried the same on MacOs. I installed the gcc, glib and tried the above command. But I am getting the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_g_obejct_new", referenced from:
      _my_obejct_new in program-4735d1.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Now I have tried different things like building the glib library as mentioned [here](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-building.html)

But still gave the same error.

Also important thing to note is that the ubuntu also have the architeture **x86_64** which I found out by running the command `uname-m`

Comment: Do you have a typo in the error message? `_g_obejct_new` looks strange. Should it be `_g_object_new`?

Comment: @Bodo thanks for pointing it out. It solved the issue.